# Is there any library does minidump on Mac?

Tags: debugging, macos, crash-dumps, crash-reports

MiniDump is a great feature for debugging crashes on Windows, especially because it is small, so it can be sent via crash reports. (Window Error Reporting).

But it seems Mac OS X and other BSD system only supports full core dump.

Is there any mini-dump implementation on Mac or BSD system? Or how does Mac software developer analyze customer's crash reports?

Thanks!
-Jonny

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use [Google breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/), which works on Windows, Mac, and Linux. As an added bonus, the file format it creates is the same as the windows minidump format, no matter what platform it's using - so you can apply your current analysis tools to dumps from windows clients.

Comment: did you mean "to dumps from non-windows clients"?

Comment: Yes, I mean this library can be used to make and upload minidumps from non-windows clients. It can also be used to make and upload minidumps from windows clients as well :)

Comment: Thanks bdonlan, breakpad is exactly I'm looking for!

Comment: Just for reference, both Firefox and Chrome are using Breakpad for crash reporting on Windows, Mac and Linux.